# CropImageView Transaction too large Exception

Tags: android, android-intent

I am having trouble with a transaction too large exception related to the cropImageView. Anytime I use the cropImageView to crop an image and then use an intent to change the activity, it gives me a Transaction too large exception.

I went on and saw that it may be cause I am passing too much data from one activity to another but even when I took the part of my code that passes a byte array in the intent it still crashes with the transaction too large exception.

Here is my code:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CropImageView cropImageView;
private Button cropImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    cropImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cropImage);
    cropImageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.cropImageView);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    byte[]  bite = intent.getExtras().getByteArray("imageForCropping");

    Bitmap bitmap = getPhoto(bite);

    cropImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    cropImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Bitmap bit = cropImageView.getCroppedImage();
            byte[] byteArray = getBytes(bit);
            Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("croppedImage", byteArray);
            TestActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });



}

public static Bitmap getPhoto(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length );

}

public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap image) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}

}
```

I have tried to avoid using this intent to pass the byte array by using a sqlite database but it still crashes with a transaction too large exception. So this led me to believe that CropImageView is causing the problem.

Please let me know if you know what the problem could be.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the `cropImageView`, it attempts to save the image as its own view state when `onSaveInstanceState()` is called.

The solution is to save the image out into a file, and call `setImageBitmap(null)` on the crop image view before calling `super.onSaveInstanceState()`, then restore the image bitmap when needed from the file.

---

EDIT: Okay, I'll share my code on this, but it's really really hacky. I was happy that it worked. Also, it's from a camera, so I took the photo and got the bitmap as a byte array.

Please advise caution.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    if(cameraPresenter != null) {
        cameraPresenter.onResume();
    }
    if(takenBitmap != null && !takenBitmap.isRecycled()) {
        takenPhotoDisplay.setImageBitmap(takenBitmap);
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewDestroyed(boolean removedByFlow) {
    takenPhotoDisplay.setImageBitmap(null);
}

@Override // called before `Activity super.onSaveInstanceState()`
public void preSaveViewState(Bundle bundle) {
    takenPhotoDisplay.setImageBitmap(null);
}

private byte[] takenPhoto;
private Bitmap takenBitmap;


private void restoreBitmap() {
    try {
        takenPhoto = readByteArrayFromFile("TEMP");
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "No bitmap found to restore");
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not read bitmap");
    }
}

private byte[] readByteArrayFromFile(String fileName)
        throws IOException {
    Context context = CustomApplication.get();
    byte[] result = null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    try {
        fileInputStream = context.openFileInput(fileName);
        result = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileInputStream);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "The file was not found [" + fileName + "]", e);
        throw e;
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to read data from stream [" + fileName + "]", e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if(fileInputStream != null) {
            try {
                fileInputStream.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close.");
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}


private void preserveBitmap() {
    if(takenPhoto != null) {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        try {
            fileOutputStream = CustomApplication.get().openFileOutput("TEMP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fileOutputStream.write(takenPhoto);
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not open temp");
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not write temp");
        } finally {
            if(fileOutputStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Nobody cares!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void destroyCurrentBitmap() {
    if(takenBitmap != null) {
        takenPhotoDisplay.setImageBitmap(null);
        takenBitmap.recycle();
        takenBitmap = null;
        takenPhoto = null;
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    }
}

private void handleTakenPhoto(byte[] data) {
    CameraView.this.takenPhoto = data;
    if(takenPhoto != null) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(takenPhoto, 0, takenPhoto.length, options);
        Log.d(TAG, "The Bitmap has width [" + bm.getWidth() + "] and height [" + bm.getHeight() + "]");
        // Setting post rotate to 90
        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        Log.i(TAG, "CURRENT ROTATION ANGLE: [" + getRotationAngle() + "]");
        // Rotating Bitmap
        mtx.postRotate(getRotationAngle());
        // Flipping bitmap
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(getActiveCameraId(), info);
        if(info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            mtx.postScale(-1, 1, bm.getWidth() / 2, bm.getHeight() / 2);
        }
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), mtx, true);
        if(bm != newBitmap) {
            bm.recycle();
            bm = newBitmap; //yes, this is on purpose!
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "The created bitmap is the same as the previous one.");
        }
        bm = newBitmap; //yes, this is on purpose!
        takenBitmap = bm;
        if(takenBitmap != null && !takenBitmap.isRecycled()) {
            takenPhotoDisplay.setImageBitmap(takenBitmap);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "The bitmap in [takenBitmap] is recycled!");
            takenPhotoDisplay.setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "The taken photo is NULL.");
    }
}

//IMAGE ROTATION FIX
public int getRotationAngle(int cameraId) {
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    Activity activity = ActivityUtils.getActivity(getContext());
    WindowManager windowManager = activity.getWindowManager();
    Display defaultDisplay = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    int rotation = defaultDisplay.getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch(rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }
    int result;
    //if(info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
    //    result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
    //    result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
    //} else { // back-facing
    //    result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    //}
    if(info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 540) % 360;
        } else {
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
    } else {
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? I am a little confused on the part on the part about super.onSaveInstanceState() and restoring the bitmap. @EpicPandaForce

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass bytes of image in intent or anywhere. Save it on disk, pass only the URI, and read image from disk